Permissions of my packages are requested on launch in flutter ios
My app has rejected for over 2 weeks from iOS app review.
The reason why it is rejected is that my app crashes right after app launches only on iPad.

Steps leading to crash:

Launched the app

Blank screen appeared

Then the app crashed



I tried to generate crash with iPad Air 5th-generation that was used for review test and other iPad simulators, but app is launched successfully on all iPad devices from my side.
crash log that I got is below:
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: app<com.chungchunon.chungchunon-ios(6C7CB146-DE35-4870-8CC5-7D42DD004FE1)>:23124 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.74 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Foreground
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-create
WatchdogVisibility: Foreground
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 46.680 (user 35.590, system 11.090), 29% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.192, 0% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0d4d6c8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0d50ec8 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0d50de0 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e0d50c20 mach_msg + 24
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a001db18 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 544
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a001deb8 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 60
6   libxpc.dylib                           0x1f4b81ac8 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 264
7   LocationSupport                        0x1b782a818 CLConnection::sendMessageSync(std::__1::shared_ptr<CLConnectionMessage>, bool) + 168
8   LocationSupport                        0x1b782a708 CLConnectionClient::sendMessageSync(std::__1::shared_ptr<CLConnectionMessage>, bool) + 120
9   CoreMotion                             0x1a51f5830 0x1a4e31000 + 3950640
10  CoreMotion                             0x1a51f571c 0x1a4e31000 + 3950364
11  CoreMotion                             0x1a51f613c 0x1a4e31000 + 3952956
12  CoreMotion                             0x1a4e41650 0x1a4e31000 + 67152
13  CoreMotion                             0x1a4e33f1c 0x1a4e31000 + 12060
14  pedometer                              0x105cd8d68 @objc StepDetector.init() + 92
15  pedometer                              0x105cd8e74 specialized static SwiftPedometerPlugin.register(with:) + 52
16  pedometer                              0x105cd8050 @objc static SwiftPedometerPlugin.register(with:) + 32
17  Runner                                 0x10437c550 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] (in Runner) (GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:251) + 17744
18  Runner                                 0x10437c8c8 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) (in Runner) (<compiler-generated>:7) + 18632
19  UIKitCore                              0x19a821bac -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 320
20  UIKitCore                              0x19a81f0e8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2856
21  UIKitCore                              0x19a6ed99c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 856
22  UIKitCore                              0x19a6a0ad8 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132
23  UIKitCore                              0x19a593708 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
24  UIKitCore                              0x19a766488 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216
25  UIKitCore                              0x19a766198 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 220
26  UIKitCore                              0x19a4f5360 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 608
27  UIKitCore                              0x19a4c2594 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 248
28  UIKitCore                              0x19a4c1ebc __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148
29  UIKitCore                              0x19a4c1868 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736
30  UIKitCore                              0x19a4c0ea8 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
31  UIKitCore                              0x19a594c80 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316
32  UIKitCore                              0x19a5934b8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.226 + 612
33  UIKitCore                              0x19a592e10 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216
34  UIKitCore                              0x19a65df48 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244
35  UIKitCore                              0x19a65aaac -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 508
36  UIKitCore                              0x19a65a6cc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
37  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0eea974 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 324
38  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0eea808 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108 + 280
39  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0ee66cc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
40  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0eeacc4 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352
41  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0002dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
42  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a000686c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 288
43  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0ee7d58 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
44  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0ee7cd8 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240
45  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b0ee7bb0 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
46  CoreFoundation                         0x19812f834 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
47  CoreFoundation                         0x19812f7c8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
48  CoreFoundation                         0x19812d2f8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
49  CoreFoundation                         0x19812c484 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
50  CoreFoundation                         0x19812bcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
51  GraphicsServices                       0x1dcb791a8 GSEventRunModal + 164
52  UIKitCore                              0x19a765ae8 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
53  UIKitCore                              0x19a819d98 UIApplicationMain + 340
54  Runner                                 0x10437caf4 main (in Runner) (AppDelegate.swift:6) + 19188
55  dyld                                   0x1bb903154 start + 2356

And I got advice from apple developer as below:

The top few frames here look like you're waiting on a system resource
in relation to permission to access privacy-sensitive data, such as
location or motion. However, the bottom frames show that your app
hasn't even finished the full launch process yet before requesting
such permissions. Since your app hasn't finished launching yet, this
is way too early, as you don't even have your app UI up and running at
this point in the launch yet. Further, requesting permissions right at
launch (even at a launch point later than this) is rarely the right
choice. The Human Interface Guidelines have information on when to
request permission to guide your users to why you need such
permissions.

So now I am assuming that package pedometer causes time out issue since it requests permission before app launches and does other heavy work.
But I don't know why it requests permissions before app launches.
Since I get step count from this package, I build app to request permission 'activityRecognition' for android and 'sensor' for ios when user clicks the specific button.
These permissions should be requested long after app launched and even when user clicks the button.
And permission 'notification' which is other permission that I use in my app is requested as well before app launches like below.
As you can see, before app is launched this permission request dialog pops up.

I look into main.dart code at first.
main.dart
void main() async {
  await runZonedGuarded(() async {
    try {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
      KakaoSdk.init(nativeAppKey: dotenv.env["KAKAO_NATIVE_APP_KEY"]);

      if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        );
      }

      await Supabase.initialize(
        url: dotenv.env["SUPABASE_URL"]!,
        anonKey: dotenv.env["SUPABASE_ANONKEY"]!,
      );

      await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);

      await StepNotification().initializeService();
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(messagingBackgroundHandler);

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
        await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
          const Duration(hours: 8),
          10,
          stepAlarmManager,
          allowWhileIdle: true,
          wakeup: true,
          rescheduleOnReboot: true,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("initialize app: $e");
    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      runApp(
        const riverpod.ProviderScope(
          child: OnldoccFlutterApp(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      final dnsCode = dotenv.env["SENTRY_DNS"];
      await SentryFlutter.init(
        (options) {
          options.dsn = dnsCode;
          options.attachStacktrace = true;
        },
        appRunner: () => runApp(
          const riverpod.ProviderScope(
            child: OnldoccFlutterApp(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }, (exception, stackTrace) async {
    Sentry.captureException(exception, stackTrace: stackTrace);
  });
}

The only code regarding package pedometer is StepNotification().initializeService(); from main.dart.
So I moved code StepNotification().initializeService(); that initialize process to count user's step into another part of app for test and submit this app.
But that app is also rejected with same issue.
[PS]

StepNotification().initializeService() initialized flutter_background_service and after user chooses to start background service, pedometer package will be initialized.

Since I already tested as moving this to another part, I guess that this line is not causing error.

And even this line also don't initialize package pedometer at the moment when app is on launch.


I look into AppDelegate.swift code on next.
AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_background_service_ios

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    SwiftFlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.taskIdentifier = "dev.flutter.background.refresh"
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


I think when GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self) is executed, all packages request corresponding permission before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions step and it takes long time.
But It's also weird that before 2weeks, I haven't get rejected from app review with this issue even though AppDelegate.swift code is same.
I don't know why this error happens suddenly even only on iPad that iOS test team uses.
And I'm also curious why notification permission request pops up before app launches and how to block this.
Podfile is attached for your reference.
Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    ... # Here are some configurations automatically generated by flutter
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    # Start of the permission_handler configuration
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   
      # You can enable the permissions needed here. For example to enable camera
      # permission, just remove the `#` character in front so it looks like this:
      #
      # ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
      # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
      #
      #  Preprocessor definitions can be found in: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler_apple/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
  
        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

        # dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   
           
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
   
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
   
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
      ]
  
    end 
    # End of the permission_handler configuration
  end
end

⭐️ package 'pedometer'
StepNotification class that I create
class StepNotification {
  Future<void> initializeService() async {
    final String stepPrefsName = "${todayToStringLine()}_stepCount";

    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      notificationChannelId,
      notificationChannelName,
      description: "This channel is used for step notification.",
      importance: Importance.low,
      playSound: false,
      enableVibration: false,
    );

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotifiationPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
      await flutterLocalNotifiationPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(
          iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
          android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/noti_icon'),
        ),
      );
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await sharedPreferences.reload();
    int todayStepCount = sharedPreferences.getInt(stepPrefsName) ?? 0;

    await flutterLocalNotifiationPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await service.configure(
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        foregroundServiceNotificationId: stepNotificationId,
        onStart: onStart,
        autoStart: false,
        autoStartOnBoot: false,
        notificationChannelId: notificationChannelId,
        initialNotificationTitle: "$todayStepCount 걸음",
        initialNotificationContent: "",
        isForegroundMode: true,
        foregroundServiceTypes: [
          AndroidForegroundType.health,
        ],
      ),
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        autoStart: false,
        onForeground: onStart,
        onBackground: onIosBackground,
      ),
    );

    // service.startService();
  }
}

// background
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

    try {
      await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
      await initializeSupabase();
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("initialize database: $e");
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    StepEventCount stepEventCount = StepEventCount();
    StepRepository stepRepository = StepRepository();
    CareRepository careRepository = CareRepository();

    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
        service.setAsForegroundService();
      });
      service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
        service.setAsBackgroundService();
      });

      service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
        service.stopSelf();
      });
    }

    // link step event count
    stepEventCount.initializeStepCount();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  try {
    await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
    await initializeSupabase();
  } catch (e) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print("initialize database: $e");
  }

  StepEventCount stepEventCount = StepEventCount();
  StepRepository stepRepository = StepRepository();

  stepEventCount.initializeStepCount();
  return true;
}

StepEventCount class that I create
class StepEventCount {
  late Stream<StepCount> stepCountStream;
  late Stream<PedestrianStatus> pedestrianStatusStream;

  void onStepCount(StepCount event) async {
    await initializeSupabase();

    final String stepPrefsName = "${todayToStringLine()}_stepCount";
    final String totalStepPrefsName = "${todayToStringLine()}_totalStepCount";

    StepRepository stepRepository = StepRepository();

    int totalCount = event.steps;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.reload();
    await sharedPreferences.setInt(totalStepPrefsName, totalCount);

    try {
      // totalCount 0인가?
      if (totalCount == 0) {
        // 오늘 걸음수 있는가?
        if (sharedPreferences.containsKey(stepPrefsName)) {
          // 오늘 걸음수 있으면
          int todayStepCount = sharedPreferences.getInt(stepPrefsName) ?? 0;
          sharedPreferences.setInt("dummy", -todayStepCount);
        } else {
          // 오늘 걸음수 없으면
          int dbTodayStepCount = await stepRepository.fetchUserTodayStepCount();
          // database 오늘 값 0인가?
          if (dbTodayStepCount != 0) {
            // 0이 아니면
            await sharedPreferences.setInt("dummy", -dbTodayStepCount);
            await sharedPreferences.setInt(stepPrefsName, dbTodayStepCount);
          } else {
            // 0이면

            await sharedPreferences.setInt("dummy", totalCount);
            await sharedPreferences.setInt(stepPrefsName, 0);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (sharedPreferences.containsKey(stepPrefsName) &&
            sharedPreferences.containsKey("dummy")) {
          int dummyCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("dummy") ?? 0;

          if (totalCount < dummyCount) {
            await sharedPreferences.setInt("dummy", totalCount);
            await sharedPreferences.setInt(stepPrefsName, 0);
          } else {
            int todayStepCount = totalCount - dummyCount;
            await sharedPreferences.setInt(stepPrefsName, todayStepCount);
          }
        } else {
          await sharedPreferences.setInt("dummy", totalCount);
          await sharedPreferences.setInt(stepPrefsName, 0);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("step_event_count: $e");
    }
  }

  void onPedestrianStatusChanged(PedestrianStatus event) {}

  void onPedestrianStatusError(error) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print("onPedestrianStatusError: $error");
  }

  void onStepCountError(error) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print("onStepCountError: $error");
  }

  Future<bool> _checkActivityRecognitionPermission() async {
    bool androidGranted = await Permission.activityRecognition.isGranted;
    bool iosGranted = await Permission.sensors.isGranted;
    return Platform.isAndroid ? androidGranted : iosGranted;
  }

  void initializeStepCount() async {
    bool permissionGranted = await _checkActivityRecognitionPermission();
    if (!permissionGranted) {
      return;
    } else {
      stepCountStream = Pedometer.stepCountStream;
      stepCountStream
          .listen(onStepCount, cancelOnError: true)
          .onError(onStepCountError);

      pedestrianStatusStream = Pedometer.pedestrianStatusStream;
      pedestrianStatusStream
          .listen(onPedestrianStatusChanged, cancelOnError: true)
          .onError(onPedestrianStatusError);
    }
  }
}


I'm so frustrated due to this same issue for 2 weeks.
Any any any little help would be grateful.
Please help me 

You should provide details on which pedometer package you are using. Is StepNotification your class?  If so, provide that code

@Paulw11 Thanks for your trying to help me. I add all information on my post.

When the Core Motion startUpdates function is called, iOS will show a permissions dialog if required. The pedometer package you are using calls startUpdates in the StepCount  onListen method.  You need to ensure that your app does not start listening to that event source until you are ready for a permission dialog to be shown.
